# is possible to see a previous row after a selected one?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have created a table  like this

```
create table numbers(

first int ...

second int...

third int ...

fourth ....

fifth int..

sixt int ...

id primary key..
...);
```

every sextain has an id for identification.

i would like to see a previuous row of the one i selected
example

```
select * from numbers where first=6 And second=54;
```

as output (we will have all the numbers were first and second are  6 and  54 with id)

```
first   second  3    4    5   6    id

6        54    10   11   13  66    10


6        54    7    8    9   10    520
```

i would like too see  row 9 and row 519 is there a way to see those? i know i 
could do

```
select * from numbers where id=9;
select * from nbumbers where id= 519;
```

but i have 50-60 row  it's impossible to do 
individually one by one.

Comment: I removed all three database tags. Please tag the one you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
SELECT * FROM NUMBERS WHERE ID IN 
(SELECT ID -1 FROM NUMBERS WHERE first = 6 and second = 54);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select n.*
from (select n.*,
             lead(first) over (order by id) as next_first,
             lead(second) over (order by id) as next_second
      from numbers n
     ) n
where next_first = 6 and next_second = 54;
```

Another method would use a cumulative sum:

```
select n.*
from (select n.*,
             max(case when first = 6 and second = 54 then id end) over
                 (order by id
                  rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                 ) as prev_id
      from numbers n
     ) n
where prev_id = id;
```

Comment: thanks !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! this is a huge way to think. I need to practice more !!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
select
  n.*
from (
  select * from numbers where first = 6 and second = 54
) x
join numbers n on n.id = x.id - 1
```

Comment: nice i did no t think i could use a join...  that was a smart way to think